# Does an Alchemist have any means to recall Infused Extracts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, alchemist

The [Infusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/infusion) Discovery allows Alchemist to provide their Extracts to non-Alchemist for use. However it inlcudes the caveat:

> ...it continues to occupy one of the alchemist’s daily extract slots.

Does an Alchemist have any way to reclaim their Extract slot if the Extract given to the +0 Perception Fighter gets pilfered by a street thief, or do they have to track that Extract down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### An alchemist that gets robbed of one or more extracts should probably only need to wait 1 day to recover the previously occupied extract slots

On [alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Alchemist/#TOC-Alchemy-Su-) says, "An extract, once created, remains potent for 1 day before becoming inert, so an alchemist must re-prepare his extracts every day." This GM would rule that an *inert* extract isn't *really* properly an extract anymore but just a useless concoction of once-magical ingredients. So, in light of the discovery [infusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/infusion), because the extract no longer exists *as an extract* after 1 day, this GM would rule that after 1 day the stolen extract no longer occupies one of the alchemist's daily extract slots.

However, were another GM to rule extracts *remain* extracts *beyond* 1 day, the alchemist could see that extract slot occupied forevermore if, for instance, the extract thief, while exploring alone, fell into a pit and died, stolen extract in his belt pouch. That would be stupid and terrible, especially considering the tendency of some GMs to have the PCs robbed or captured and stripped of their gear. If the GM rules this way and possesses such tendencies, this player recommends picking a class other than alchemist or, at least, a discovery other than infusion.

Comment: Ah. I realize now that my interpretation was largely based by missing the context of the quote I used.

Comment: @Ifusaso Dude, don't take that blame. It's a perfectly legitimate question, really, and it should've been addressed in the infusion discovery instead of forcing readers to guess or the GM to rule.